# Creating User-Mode Video Filter Driver

Tags: windows, video, driver, video-processing

The company I work for would like to modify all video being sent to a Monitor using Windows 10.  Is it possible to write a user-mode filter driver that will sit on top of the vendor driver to modify the video being sent to the display?

By video I mean anything being displayed on the screen. (Desktop, programs, media, etc.) Think of it as a heads-up display but the data is based on the value of the pixels. i.e. input pixel value of 100, change it (100 * 0.9), send 90 to the monitor(different modifications for each pixel). Ideally would be applying this to any monitor connected to the computer. Ideally, this would look something like a video driver that intercepts the display data before going to the video card driver, modify it then pass it to the video card.

Comment: _"...Would like to modify all video being sent to a Monitor"_ Not enough useful info to get an answer. **(1)** What is the purpose (problem to solve) by modifying video? **(2)** Is the monitor a second (external) screen connected to the Win10 computer? **(3)** Are your videos being played by your own custom player (meaning that grabbing frames to modify (the pixels) before showing in app window is a possibility)?...

Comment: By video I mean anything being displayed on the screen. (Desktop, programs, media, etc.)  Think of it as a heads-up display but the data is based on the value of the pixels.  i.e. input pixel value of 100, change it (100 * 0.9), send 90 to the monitor(different modification for each pixel).  Ideally would be applying this to any monitor connected to the computer.  Ideally, this would look something like a video driver that intercepts the display data before going to the video card driver, modify it then pass it to the video card.